# Applying a threshold to all values in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of 1000 elements, which elements fluctuate from 0 to 1.

I want to scan that array and zero all values below a certain threshold, let's say, `0.3`.

I know I can do something like

```
let filteredArrayOnDict = myArray.filter { $0 > 0.3}
```

and I will get a new array with the elements above `0.3`. But that is not what I want. I want to zero the elements below 0.3 and keep the resulting array with the same number of elements.

I can iterate over the array like

```
var newArray : [Double] = []
for item in myArray {
  if item > 0.3 {
    newArray.append(item)
  } else {
    newArray.append(0)
  }
}
```

but I wonder if there is some more elegant method using these magical commands like filter, map, flatmap, etc.

Comment: `array.map { $0 > 0.3 ? $0 : 0 }`

Comment: ahhhhhhh... can I do that inside map? AMAZING. Please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try map for this

```
var resultArray = myArray.map({$0 > 0.3 ? $0 : 0})
```

Answer (score 6):

The [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate) has a dedicated function [`vDSP_vthresD`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450767-vdsp_vthresd) for this purpose:

> Vector threshold with zero fill; double precision.

Example:

```
import Accelerate

let array = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
var threshold = 0.3
var result = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: array.count)
vDSP_vthresD(array, 1, &threshold, &result, 1, vDSP_Length(array.count))
print(result) // [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
```